# What is the term used to describe assigning values to an object without first instantiating it?

Tags: java, terminology, instantiation

E.g.

`Car myCar = Car.Ford`

instead of

```
Car myCar = new Car();
myCar = Car.Ford
```

Comment: I think it's called "not wasting time creating useless objects and throwing them away".

Comment: `myCar` is a variable not an object. You don't assign values to an object but to it's fields.

Comment: actually wait. Why am I throwing the object away? In the first example myCar is still a Car object , so surely a Car object must also have been created to hold the Car.Ford value?

Comment: @Besh - yeah but Car.Ford is not a value...right? It's like Color.Red, just a specific type of Color...object....

Comment: Looks like `Ford` is an static field in the class `Car` which refers to an instance of `Car`. First one looks ok. But in the second one you are creating an instance yourself `new Car();` but then you let it go by doing `myCar = Car.Ford;`.

Comment: @tetris11 - You instantiate a car object and assign it to `myCar`. You then discard that object by assigning `Car.Ford` (Whatever that is) to `myCar`. It's unclear what this code does, or why you would ever have something like `Car.Ford` - it's almost like you're not understanding either inheritance or a factory pattern.

Comment: Wait..... I just got this. Okay but Im still confused when it comes to Color objects. When I do `Color myRed = Color.Red` im actually just accessing a static field within the Color class, and NOT accessing a specific Color object (whose properties are red paint)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a separate term. You appear to understand the terms assignment, and instantiation. You're just looking for `non-instantation assignment at time of declaration`?

Comment: Okay, I've realised that I've confused a static variable in the class Cars, with an actual Car object.

Comment: @Tetris11 Yes, it is possible that Car.Ford is still null.